# Unable to create workspace on ROS foxy

Tags: ubuntu, ros, catkin

I tried to create catkin workspace for my ROS project. First I went to the home directory of linux system (Ubuntu 20.04) and create a new folder name **Workspaces**. Then I opened the Workspaces folder and create a new folder named **test_ws** under the workspaces. Then I created a new folder named **src** under the test_ws. Then I went to terminal and typed the command **cd Workspaces/test_ws/src/** to follow that path. Then I create a catkin package from the terminal following the command **catkin_create_pkg test_pkg roscpp rospy std_msgs sensor_msgs**. Then I came back to home directory and entered to the **test_pkg** to create a folder named **scripts**. The **test_pkg contained include, scripts, src, cmakeList.txt, and package.xml**.  After that I tried to compile the project using the command **catkin_make**. I got an error "**Command 'catkin_make' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install catkin**". Then I tried this command on terminal "**~/Workspaces/test_ws$ source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash**". Then tried "**~/Workspaces/test_ws$ catkin_make**". I again got the previous error. Then I tried "**~/Workspaces/test_ws$ sudo apt install catkin**"  and get the following messages

```
Reading package lists... Done Building
dependency tree        Reading state
information... Done Some packages
could not be installed. This may mean
that you have requested an impossible
situation or if you are using the
unstable distribution that some
required packages have not yet been
created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to
 resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
catkin : Depends: python3-catkin-pkg (>= 0.4.14-2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

After that I tried "**~/Workspaces/test_ws$ sudo apt install ros-foxy-catkin**". I received the following messages

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-catkin
```

Then I tried "**sudo apt install ros2-foxy-catkin**"  I got following messages

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros2-foxy-catkin
```

Then I updated the all using sudo apt update and ran the same commands again. The errors remained same. I tried all the solution that I found on web for this error but nothing worked.

I also checked the gcc version which produced "**gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc**."

Following is my ROS version "/Workspaces/test_ws$ echo $ROS_DISTRO
**foxy**
"

Comment: What version of ROS do you actually have installed? Catkin is not for ros foxy

Comment: What can I used to compile the program instead of Catkin for ROS2 foxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment you're using the wrong build system. `Catkin` is the meta build system created for *ros1*, but for ros2 a new tool has been created called `colcon`. `Colcon` supports both python and C++ packages and they should be made using the CLI tools. For example:

```
ros2 pkg create --build-type ament_cmake <package_name>
```

Will create a `cmake` package. Instead of using `catkin_make` for a package you would now use `colcon build` in your workspace root directory.

For further information you should check out [the official documentation.](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Creating-Your-First-ROS2-Package.html)